# Linked List merging two lists, debug assertion error

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I have a merge implementation for a Linked List. It accepts two parameters of type List which is a class that includes a `Node* head` pointer and a struct `Node` consisting of a `typename T data` and a `Node* next`. The issue I'm having is that my implementation isn't linking the nodes as it should, or maybe I'm just going about it wrong. What it needs to do is, if you do `list1.merge(list2, list3);` then list1 will become the combination of list2 and list3's nodes. I need to do this by pointer manipulation and no new memory allocation, so list2 and list3 will be modified. Here is what I have right now:

```
template <typename T>
void List<T>::merge(List& list1, List& list2) {

typename List<T>::Node* list1Ptr = list1.head;
typename List<T>::Node* list2Ptr = list2.head;

for(;;) {
    if (list1Ptr == NULL && list2Ptr != NULL) {
        list1Ptr = list2Ptr->next;
        head = list1.head;
        break;
    }
    else if (list2Ptr == NULL && list1Ptr != NULL) {
        list2Ptr = list1Ptr->next;
        head = list1.head;
        break;
    }
    else if (list1Ptr == NULL && list2Ptr == NULL) {
        head = list1.head;
        break;
    }
    else if (list1Ptr != NULL && list2Ptr != NULL) {

        if (list1Ptr->data > list2Ptr->data){
            typename List<T>::Node* temp;
            temp = list2Ptr->next;
            list1Ptr->next = list1Ptr;
            list2Ptr = temp;
        }
        else if (list1Ptr->data < list2Ptr->data) {
            typename List<T>::Node* temp;
            temp = list1Ptr->next;
            list1Ptr->next = list2Ptr;
            list1Ptr = temp;
        }
        else if (list1Ptr->data == list2Ptr->data) {
            list1Ptr = list1Ptr->next;
        }
    }
}
}
```

The data that is contained in the nodes is of a class type that was provided for us, which contains all the proper overloaded operators that we need. The entire code runs just fine, until main goes out of scope and the destructor is called for what remains, after which I get a `Debug Assertion Failed Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)`.

I'm really not sure how to go about this, I've drawn it out many many times and it all seems to make sense to me. If anyone has any tips to put me in the right direction, I will greatly appreciate it. Thanks everyone for looking!

Comment: Please check you are not deleting something twice (like a node). When you are doing the merging, you don't create new objects for the list1, thus maybe you are trying to delete list1, list2 and list3.

Answer (score 1):

This does not work as expected:

```
list1Ptr->data > list2Ptr->data && list1Ptr != NULL 
             && list2Ptr != NULL
```

You need to check if a pointer is NULL before dereferencing it otherwise you will get undefined behavior. (That means anything can happen, very bad.)
Also, you should use nullptr instead of NULL.

This is however not the cause for the error message because you have checked for all the NULL cases in other conditionals.

Your problem is probably as asalic suggested. Please show us the rest of the code if you would like comments.

Answer (score 1):

Well for starters there something wrong here:

```
    if (list1Ptr == NULL && list2Ptr != NULL) {
        list1Ptr = list2Ptr;
        head = list1.head;
        break;
    }
```

If you are done traversing list1 then what you want is to point the last node of list1 to point at list2.
`list1Ptr = list2Ptr;`
is doing nothing of that. It is merely changing the local variable's value.
Same for this part:

```
    else if (list2Ptr == NULL && list1Ptr != NULL) {
        list2Ptr = list1Ptr;
        head = list1.head;
        break;
    }
```

This is a bad of doing things:
`list1Ptr->data > list2Ptr->data && list1Ptr != NULL 
             && list2Ptr != NULL`
If list1Ptr becomes NULL then if you try to access NULL->data there is surely going to be trouble(since generally the expression will be executed left to right).
Also:

```
        else if (list1Ptr->data > list2Ptr->data && list1Ptr != NULL 
             && list2Ptr != NULL) {
        typename List<T>::Node* temp = list2Ptr;
        list2Ptr = list2Ptr->next;
        temp->next = list1Ptr;
        }
```

There is something really wrong here too. You first store list2ptr in a temp. Then you move list2ptr to the next node in list2. But why make `temp->next = list1ptr`?
You should be re thinking that part out. And same for the next else block.
Best.
EDIT:
Alright, let's see what more can be done:
Here is the psuedo code I suggest you use:

```
func(list1,list2):
ptr1 = list1.head
ptr2 = list2.head
declare pointer curr
if(ptr1!= NULL and ptr2!=NULL){
    if(ptr1->data < prt2->data)
    {curr = ptr1
    ptr1 = ptr1->next
    head = curr
    }
    else{
    curr = ptr2
    ptr1 = ptr2->next
    head = curr}}
else{
    head = whichever one is not NULL, or NULL if both of them are and return
    }
while(ptr1 != NULL and ptr2!=NULL){
    if(ptr1->data < ptr2->data){
    curr->next = ptr1
    curr = ptr1
    ptr1 = ptr1->next
    continue}
    else{
    curr->next = ptr2
    curr = ptr2
    ptr2 = ptr2->next
    continue}
}
if(ptr1 == NULL)
    curr->next = ptr2
else
    curr->next = ptr1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will work on it with those tips in mind definitely!

Comment: Made some changes but it still seems to be doing the same thing, no matter how much I alter it. I debugged with some couts and it seems that this is not merging the two lists, or setting the other list to the merged list.

Comment: @floatfil Alright, added psuedo code, which might help you out.

Comment: Also you should understand each and every line of psuedo code, and understand why it works - in case this is a homework question.